# Data transfer from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, windows, transfer

When one installs Ubuntu, is all the XP data (programs, document files, favourites, etc..) transferred to Ubuntu as well?  If not, what is the suggested process?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what abuntu is, but i suppose that answer is no.
Programs from Windows are different to one from Ubuntu, but you can use Wine - Windows emulator for Ubuntu. You can create another partition for Ubuntu and use these systems both, as well you can run windows apps on linux by Wine and starting them from Windows OS partition. Only one thing to do here is to install Ubuntu next to Windows and mount your NTFS Windows partition in Ubuntu.

I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what do you want to do either complete fresh install of Ubuntu or DualBoot, complete guide how to install [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) and more details about partitions you'll be needed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)